# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2n+k)}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> How to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2n+k)}{n^n}\quad ?$$

*Wolfram Alpha* says that it's $\frac{27}{4{e}}$, but I fail to arrive at this result.

Methods allowed in my class so far are pretty limited - I've tried treating the product in the numerator as a polynomial (it's a product of n linear terms) and finding the coefficient at $n^n$, the highest power - but it seems to be the wrong approach. May anyone help me, please?

Comment: Looks like a Riemann sum if you take logarithm of $$\prod_{k=1}^n\left( \frac{2n+k}{n}\right)^{1/n}$$

Comment: Sorry, take logarithm of $$\left[\prod_{k=1}^n\left( \frac{2n+k}{n}\right)\right]^{1/n} $$ and then take the limit.

Answer (score 5):

Not too bad after taking the log,
$$\log\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\left( \frac{2n+k}{n}\right)^{1/n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\log\left(2+\tfrac{k}{n}\right) = \int_0^1\log(2+x)dx$$
Should be able to do the rest from here.

Comment: Of course, order of taking log and limit does not matter.